# How can you ignore the end of a URL using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to structure my website like this:

```
domain.com/person/edit/1
domain.com/person/edit/2
domain.com/person/edit/3
etc.
```

I have a page to which all these requests should go:

```
domain.com/person/edit.html
```

The JavaScript will look at the trailing part of the url when the page is loaded so I want the server to internally ignore it.

I've got this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^person/view/(.*)$ person/view.html [L]
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious but when I visit one of the pages above I get this 404 message:

```
The requested URL /person/view.html/1 was not found on this server.
```

As far as I understood it the [L] means that if this rule applies Apache should stop rewriting and serve up the alternate page. Instead it seems to be applying the rule at the earliest possible moment and then appending the rest of the unmatched url to the re-written one.

How do I get these re-writes to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"As far as I understood it the [L] means that if this rule applies Apache should stop rewriting and serve up the alternate page."*

Well .. `[L]` flag tells Apache to stop checking other rules .. and rewrite goes to next iteration  .. where it again checks against all rules again (that is how it works).

Try these "recipe" (put it somewhere on top of your .htaccess):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
```

---

Another idea to try -- add `DPI` flag to your `[L]`: `[L,DPI]`

---

If `Options` will not help, then rewrite rule should. But it all depends on your Apache's configuration. If the above does not work -- please post your whole .htaccess (update your question).

Comment: Fantastic! I disabled multiviews and it seems to work. The multiviews option scans for similarly named files within directories, is that right? So my server was finding the edit.html file and rewriting to that without checking the .htaccess file first? Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 for `DPI`. I've run into some problems that only `DPI` could fix.